# Google Analytics dimension and metrics validation

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I request some metrics and dimensions (`ga:users`, `ga:1dayUsers` for example)
from google analytics i have follow error: `Ack! There was an error (400)Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together.`

In [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) guide when I check `ga:users` `ga:1dayUsers` is disabled. How to validate all combinations of metrics and dimensions for querying?

Answer (score 1):

At this time there is no way to programmatically validate them.  There is also no way to programmatically validate the query without just sending it to google and see if it works or not.

You can manually check if they can be combined using the [Dimensions and metrics explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

[image]

Comment: But in [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) guide google validate it. How to get this validation rules?

Comment: By clicking on the check boxes. There is no other way of doing it.  Google hasn't released any rules stating what is valid or what isn't valid nor have they released an API that lets us test it.